# Mule HTTP connection reset

Tags: java, http, tomcat, mule, tomcat8

I have mule application deployed on tomcat Web-Server. i am exposing web service and using the below HTTP connector

```
<http:inbound-endpoint host="0.0.0.0" port="9198"  path="customer/payment/debit" exchange-pattern="request-response">
             <mule-ss:http-security-filter realm="mule-realm" securityProviders="userprovider"  />            
        </http:inbound-endpoint>
```

then i am using jaxws-service for publish the web-service

```
<cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.cit.wsdl.customer.payment.debit.v1_0.PaymentDebit" service="PaymentDebitService" soapVersion="1.2" />
```

the problem that i am getting the below error :

> ERROR org.mule.module.logging.DispatchingLogger : Caught exception in
>   Exception Strategy: Connection resetjava.net.SocketException:
>   Connection reset at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:196) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122) at
>   java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
>   at
>   org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
>   at
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.readLine(HttpServerConnection.java:243)
>   at
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpServerConnection.getRequestLine(HttpServerConnection.java:509)
>   at
>   org.mule.transport.http.HttpRequestDispatcherWork.run(HttpRequestDispatcherWork.java:70)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>   at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

The client get the below error :

> "Exception: An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to
>   http://10.255.142.36:9198/customer/payment/debit. This could be due
>   to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This
>   could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the
>   server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs
>   for more details. "

The above error is happened randomly but there are requests successfully received to the server and handled by mule.

Answer (score 0):

'java.net.SocketException: Connection reset' is not something failing in Mule OR tomcat, but it is failing at tcp level.

Looks like Http(application) level communication established between client and Mule/tomcat(as tcp acknowledgement received from server) and then tcp connection got reset, to figure out root cause you need to use wireshark. alternately you need to make sure there is no network connection drop.